# Adding Total from Items in Database in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to write a code that creates a `while True` loop and asks the user to select an item(s) from the grocery list displayed. When the user is finished, I want to break out of the loop, and have the total price of those items calculated and printed to screen.

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('seasonalProduce.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS productList (
     productID integer PRIMARY KEY,
     productName text NOT NULL,
     productPrice real
);""")



#add rows (records) to the productList table

productRecords = [(1, "Apples", 4.59),
            (2, "Grapes", 5.99),
            (3, "Pumpkin", 3.00),
            (4, "Strawberries", 2.50),
            (5, "Leafy Greens", 4.00)]
            
cursor.executemany("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO productList (productID, productName, productPrice) VALUES(?,?,?);", productRecords)

connection.commit()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM productList;")

produce = cursor.fetchall()

for rows in produce:
print(rows)

connection.close()


while True:
    while True:
        try:
        choice1 = input("Please enter the product ID number:")
        if choice1 in range(8):
            print("Thank you. Please enter the price of the item.")
            price1 = input(float("price per kg:"))
            break
        else:
            print("Please try again. Enter a number within range 1 to 7.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input. Please try again.")

        while True:
            choice2 = input("Please enter the product ID number:")
            if choice2 in range(8):
                print("Thank you.Please enter the price of the item.")
                price1 = input(float("price per kg:"))
                price2 = input(float("price per kg:"))
                break
            else:
                print("Please try again. Enter a number within range 1 to 7.")
    try:
        userContinue = input("Would you like to add another item to your purchase? Y/N: ")
        if userContinue.upper() == "Y":
            choice3 = input("Please enter the product ID number:")
        elif userContinue.upper() == "N":
            total = price1 + price2
            print("Your total is", total)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input. Please try again.")`
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I ask the user to select an item from the list, put in the price, ask if they want to continue their purchase or are finished, and then calculate the total price.

Comment: @TashiHiggins That looks like 5 questions. From glancing at your code, you seem to have already attempted these. Which one are you having trouble with?

Comment: Haha, yes! I am definitely a beginner. How to use the product ID to associate it the price. And the second part would be asking the user how many kilos, and doing a weight * price dependent on the product ID they put in.

Comment: I hope I'm clear. I basically want to use indexing or a for statement, I'm not sure!

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in the code. There are many indentation errors when you were executing iterations. The while and try statements along with indentation errors caused a lot of conflict in the program. Hence it must be removed.

Another problem was in the if statements after the choice input. We must convert the string to integer before we proceed. Convert the weight from string separately. The code does not add and display sum if the user entered 3 products.

If you want the users to be able to add endless amount of products, we can try the while loop instead of the if loop in the last choice. what it basically does is while userContinue equals Y, it will ask the user to add another product and add its weight to the total. in the end it will ask the user again as to if he wants to enter another product.

Thus the user can add infinite number of products. if the user gives N, then it moves out of the loop and prints the total stored in the variable total. creating this variable should also fix the totaling issue. So first we add a cursor command where instead of asking the user to enter the price, it commands SQL to fetchone() the price associated with the given product id. it comes in a tuple form and we convert it to float using the float() join() and str() functions.

We also specify a statement if which functions to tell the user if that they have entered a value for the product id which is not there in the database. We do so by checking if that field is null or not. It allows the user to enter again. Lastly we must allow the user to select their preferred weight.

We receive the input and convert it to float as the value can be in decimals depending on the users need (e.g. 2.5 kg). We also multiply it with the cost before adding it to the total variable. I have also made a few changes in the print commands, check it out. I have also shifted the closing connection line to the end as we perform many operations with the database in the middle  here is the code with all the changes implemented:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('seasonalProduce.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS productList (
     productID integer PRIMARY KEY,
     productName text NOT NULL,
     productPrice real
);""")

#add rows (records) to the productList table

productRecords = [(1, "Apples", 4.59),
            (2, "Grapes", 5.99),
            (3, "Pumpkin", 3.00),
            (4, "Strawberries", 2.50),
            (5, "Leafy Greens", 4.00)]
            
cursor.executemany("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO productList (productID, productName, productPrice) VALUES(?,?,?);", productRecords)

connection.commit()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM productList;")

produce = cursor.fetchall()

for rows in produce:
    print(rows)

choice1 = input("Please enter the product ID number:")
nos1=input("Please enter the desired weight in kilograms:")
if int(choice1)in range(8):
    cursor.execute("SELECT productPrice FROM productList WHERE productID ={}".format(int(choice1)))
    price1=cursor.fetchone()
    if type(price1)=="":
        print("This product does not exist. please check your product id")
    float_price1=float('.'.join(str(i) for i in price1))
    float_nos1=float(nos1)
    p1=float_price1*float_nos1
else:
    print("There is no product under that ID. Please verify your number.")
choice2 = input("Please enter the product ID number:")
nos2=input("Please enter the desired weight in kilograms:")
if int(choice2) in range(8):
    cursor.execute("SELECT productPrice FROM productList WHERE productID ={}".format(int(choice2)))
    price2=cursor.fetchone()
    if type(price2)=="":
        print("This product does not exist. please check your product id")
    float_price2=float('.'.join(str(i) for i in price2))
    float_nos2=float(nos2)
    p2=float_price2*float_nos2
else:
    print("There is no product under that ID. Please verify your number.")
userContinue = input("Would you like to add another item to your purchase? Y/N: ")
total=p1+p2
while userContinue.upper() == "Y":
    choice3 = input("Please enter the product ID number:")
    nos3=input("Please enter the desired weight in kilograms:")
    if int(choice3) in range(8):
        cursor.execute("SELECT productPrice FROM productList WHERE productID ={}".format(int(choice3)))
        price3=cursor.fetchone()
        if type(price3)=="":
            print("This product does not exist. please check your product id")
        float_price3=float('.'.join(str(i) for i in price3))
        float_nos3=float(nos3)
        p3=float_price3*float_nos3
        total=total+p3
        userContinue = input("Would you like to add another item to your purchase? Y/N: ")
    else:
        print("There is no product under that ID. Please verify your number.")
print("Your total is", total,"\n Thank You")
connection.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It has helped tremendously. There are still some issues with error handling, that I'm trying to work on now! Other than that, it functions as it should!!

Comment: would you like me to help with the errors? is so please feel free to reach out!!!

Comment: Yes please!!! I'm working on it now and will post what I've done so far. It is a bit cluttered and complicated

Comment: It won't let me answer my own question.  But basically I've incorporated a lot of while try/except. Breaking each section up. However, I'm thinking functions would be a lot easier.